# Want to add payable message service in app

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm creating an app that send messages with some data from app. And I want to add payable message service in my app. Like first 100 messages are free than user will charged `$0.50` for every message. I have read about in app perchase from this apple [doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html). But not sure that it will fulfill my purpose. Any idea and suggestion please.

And also I want to use other messaging service in my app rather than iPhone native message. Any suggestion on this.

Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a messagingservice usualy needs a server that handles the clients. so if you have the server, you can ask for authentication and there is a possible point for requesting account information. as far as i know the in-app purchase only gives you the option to activate parts of your app, also unlocking or extending code.

but just by the way, why pay if there are already free apps/services? what is the advantage with your app?

edit
seems like you can offer virtual items (like in games). take the idea of a prepaid account and maybe its something for you ;)